# Angular 5 - Upload File to local folder

Tags: angular, typescript

I've been searching about how to upload a file(in this case an image) to a local folder in the angular project but so far i haven't found how to. I've seen i can use ng2-folder-upload but i rather to just use typescript.
Any help will be thankful!

Comment: it's not exactly clear what you mean by "upload to a local folder in the angular project", especially since Angular is a client-side framework. Can you explain?

Comment: Yeah for example i upload an image using an input then when i submit, i want that image saved in a folder called media/images/

Comment: You can't upload any file where angular is hosted. You can upload file in API folder by writing file upload method and call it from angular.

Comment: @Dhavalkansagara Oh Thanks, so i think i must find a way to use PHP for this.

Comment: @QuickAccount123 Yes PHP, C#, nodejs or any other language that you know.